# VHDL Condition in if must be static and component instantiation inside if statement

Tags: encryption, vhdl

I am implementing a block cipher(SQUARE) which consists of 8 rounds (see below). The cipher must allow two operational modes : encryption and decryption (denoted as `mode = 0` or `mode = 1` in code).

```
entity SQUARE is
Port ( mode : in  STD_LOGIC;
       squarein : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
       key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
       squareout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0) 
     );
end SQUARE;

enc : if (mode = '0') generate -- do encryption
   s0 : preround port map(squarein, key, con0, key1, rin1);
   s1 : round port map(rin1, key1, con1, key2, rin2);
   s2 : round port map(rin2, key2, con2, key3, rin3);
   s3 : round port map(rin3, key3, con3, key4, rin4);
   s4 : round port map(rin4, key4, con4, key5, rin5);
   s5 : round port map(rin5, key5, con5, key6, rin6);
   s6 : round port map(rin6, key6, con6, key7, rin7);
   s7 : round port map(rin7, key7, con7, key8, rin8);
   s8 : lastround port map(rin8, key8, squareout);
end generate;

dec : if (mode = '1') generate -- do decryption
   i8 : invround port map(squarein, key8, con7, invkey7, invrin7);
   i7 : invround port map(invrin7, invkey7, con6, invkey6, invrin6);
   i6 : invround port map(invrin6, invkey6, con5, invkey5, invrin5);
   i5 : invround port map(invrin5, invkey5, con4, invkey4, invrin4);
   i4 : invround port map(invrin4, invkey4, con3, invkey3, invrin3);
   i3 : invround port map(invrin3, invkey3, con2, invkey2, invrin2);
   i2 : invround port map(invrin2, invkey2, con1, invkey1, invrin1);
   i1 : invround port map(invrin1, invkey1, con0, invkey0, invrin0);
   i0 : invpreround port map(invrin0, invkey0, squareout);
end generate;
```

**Problem:** Compile was successful with warnings (Condition in IF GENERATE must be static). How could I avoid this warning ? Maybe rewriting the code in other fashion ..

Comment: You can only use constants (including generic parameters) in generate statements. You are using a signal. Do you want to change the mode at runtime (then you need a signal -- as you use -- and a multiplexer structure) or at compile time (then you need a generic parameter and a generate statement -- as you use)

Comment: square.vhd:9:1:error: entity, architecture, package or configuration keyword expected ... was compilation really successful?

Comment: As Brian notes your code snippet isn't valid VHDL, missing a passel of declarations including external blocks round and invround. Notice the correlation between a wavy handed question and wavy handed answer. Looking in Wei Dai's Crypt++ library implementation of square we see a separate round and invround is not necessary. If you want to switch modes on a block by block basis you can with the proper implementation. The warning is telling you it will elaborate. The results won't be useful.

Comment: I meant, more or less, to make you aware of my usecase. Anyway I accepted JHBonarius answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated by Paebbels, `generate` cannot be used dynamically. It needs to be constant at compile/synthesis time. what you could do is use a generic instead (using the VHDL-2008 if-else generate construct):

```
entity SQUARE is
    generic(mode : std_logic);
    Port ( squarein : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           squareout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0) 
    );
end entity;

architecture structural or SQUARE is
begin
    enc : if (mode = '0') generate -- do encryption
        s0 : entity work.preround port map(squarein, key, con0, key1, rin1);
        [...]
    else generate
       -- decrypt
       i8 : entity work.invround port map(squarein, key8, con7, invkey7, invrin7);
       [...]
    end generate;
end architecture;
```

If you want to change the mode of operation on the fly, you need to generate all the components, and select an output using muxes:

```
entity SQUARE is
    Port ( mode : in std_logic;
           squarein : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           key : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0);
           squareout : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (127 downto 0) 
    );
end entity;

architecture structural or SQUARE is
begin
    -- encrypt components
    s0 : entity work.preround port map(squarein, key, con0, key1, rin1);
    [...]
    s8 : entity work.lastround port map(rin8, key8, squareout_enc);
    -- decrypt components
    i8 : entity work.invround port map(squarein, key8, con7, invkey7, invrin7);
    [...]
    i0 : entity work.invpreround port map(invrin0, invkey0, squareout_dec);
    -- connect outputs
    squareout <= squareout_enc when mode='0' else squareout_dec;
end architecture;
```